# Swift how to add background color just around text in a label?

Tags: ios, swift, variables, label

How do you add a background color around each variable inside the interests variable? Just around text not the spaces.

```
var interests = "\(int01)     \(int02)     \(int03)     \(int04)     \(int05)     \(int06)"
```

I want it to look like this:
[image]

Comment: note: \(int01)... etc. may be more than one word.

Comment: Here they use different buttons to implement the same.

Comment: Consider using UICollectionView if there are unlimited words.

Comment: If each variable can have more than one word, then you can separate the words from the string and save it in an array and do what kbunarjo has suggested

Comment: Research NSAttributedSting and attributedText.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a regex to find anything but white spaces, use a while loop to find its occurrences in a string and use those ranges to change the background color of an attributed string:

**Swift 4**

```
let mutable = NSMutableAttributedString(string: interests)
var startIndex = interests.startIndex
while let range = interests.range(of: "\\S+", options: .regularExpression, range: startIndex..<interests.endIndex) {
    mutable.addAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.cyan, range: NSRange(range, in: interests))
    startIndex = range.upperBound
}
label.attributedText = mutable
```

Note: If you would like to add space around your text you can change your regex to `" \\S+ "` and don't forget to add spaces at the begin and at the end of your original interests string.

Comment: This is what I'm going with but I'm getting 2 errors. "Type 'String' has no member 'backgroundColor'" and " Value of type 'String' has no member 'attributedText'. Any idea on solutions to these? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing to get those errors. `label` should be a `UILabel` as you have asked and I am not using `backgroundColor` property in any `String`

Comment: Feel free to edit your question and post your code if you can't figure out how to implement it.

Comment: I'm just messing with it. Figured out the second error. Wasn't in the tableview cell. Working on the .backgroundColor now.

Comment: @BrettTaylor what is your Xcode/Swift Version? try `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName`

Comment: If you are not using Xcode 9.x Swift 4 you will also get an error on the range

Comment: I haven't used Swift 3 for a long time so for the range try `let location = interests.distance(from: interests.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)` and
        `let length = interests.distance(from: range.lowerBound, to: range.upperBound)` and `NSRange(location: location, length: length)`

Comment: NSBackgroundColorAttributeName fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: interests)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: yourColor, range: NSMakeRange(startOfWord, lengthOfWord))
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is use a UICollectionView with cells that have labels that span the entire cell. Each cell then corresponds to individual words. That way you can set either the label or the cell background color to whatever you want.

For ease of implementation, I would turn your `interests` variable into an array of strings. That way you can easily count the number of cells you need and give each cell the right string.

Comment: @rmaddy interesting. I probably should've done research before I said that. I edited my response. Thank you

Comment: FYI - the picture in the question looks to be from stack overflow.